# Customize JSON representation of Pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a Pydantic model defined as follows:

```py
class IntOrString(BaseModel):
    int_value: Optional[StrictInt] = None
    string_value: Optional[StrictStr] = None
```

Is there a way I can customize `json()` to make the output as follows:

```py
p = IntOrString(int_value=123)
print(p.json())
#> 123

p = IntOrString(string_value="Hello World")
print(p.json())
#> "Hello World"
```

Note: `IntOrString` can be a nested attribute of another Pydantic model.

In addition to `object` (e.g. `{"id": 123}`), `string`, `number` `boolean` are also valid JSON type. In other words, the question is can a pydantic model be serialized to `string`, `number` or `boolean` instead of `object`?

I know it's a weird requirement. Just want to know if that's possible.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you actually don't want valid JSON to be returned by the `json` method? Or do you mean you want `{"id": 123}` and `{"name": "Hello World"}` instead?

Comment: No. I simply want `123` or `"Hello World"` which are also valid JSON values.

Comment: And what should be the generalized logic behind such a method? Whenever there is only one not-`None`-field, return just the value of that field; otherwise return an object with all non-`None`-fields? In other words: What should happen, if there are more than 2 fields on a model?

Comment: I've updated the question with a bit more info. It's a weird requirement. Basically I want to serialize a pydantic model into `string` or `number`. Is that technically possible?

Comment: Of course you _can_. But you didn't answer my questions. What should happen if e.g. you have 3 fields `a`, `b`, `c`, each with `Optional[str] = None`? How should an instance be serialized, if `a` and `b` are _not_ `None`, but `c` is `None`? Like this: `{"a": "foo", "b": "bar", "c": null}`? Or without the `c` key? Do you just want the special case of _exactly one_ field being not-`None` to result in that value being returned as JSON (instead of the entire model)? What about if _all_ fields are `None`, how should that be treated? You see, your requirements are not weird, just still ambiguous.

Comment: Agreed that my question lacks details. I've updated the question with better model name to make it clear that the object only allows either integer or string values (and let's assume there's a validator to ensure only int_value or string_value is set). I want to focus on the implementation of `json()` or methods to allow returning JSON number or JSON string instead of JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple thing as excluding `None`-valued fields in the JSON representation, you can simply use the built-in [`exclude_none`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson) parameter:

```py
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictInt, StrictStr


class Dummy(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[StrictInt] = None
    name: Optional[StrictStr] = None


class Other(BaseModel):
    dummy: Dummy


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Dummy(id=123)
    print(p.json(exclude_none=True))

    p = Dummy(name="Hello World")
    print(p.json(exclude_none=True))

    o = Other(dummy=Dummy(id=123))
    print(o.json(exclude_none=True))
```

Output:

```
{"id": 123}
{"name": "Hello World"}
{"dummy": {"id": 123}}
```

---

If you want more complex stuff, you may want to provide your own custom JSON encoder either via the `encoder` parameter on a call-by-call basis or in the model config via [`json_dumps`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#custom-json-deserialisation) or `json_encoders`.